# How to close all wifi password message windows at once?

Tags: wireless, process, kill

I keep my computer on at night. During this time the router stops and starts multiple times. I have checked connect automatically to the connection. When I see the computer in the morning, I have the wireless connected but there are lots of message windows with title `Wireless Network Authentication Required`. I did `ps -e` but couldn't figure out which process are all those windows linked with. How do I close all these messages at once using some sort of `kill` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing **NetworkManager** does the trick. NetworkManager will automatically be restarted by the init system, so there's nothing more to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't try your solution. I'm not sure if NetworkManager is the offending process (please see the solution I posted).

Comment: Well, killing NetworkManager will also cause nm-applet to close, but when init restarts NetworkManager, nm-applet will respawn too. So you get the same effect with only one command.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around the following fixed the problem.

1. Run

   `xprop _NET_WM_PID`

   and click on the message window. It gives process id of the
   offending window.  Source:
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window
2. Do `ps -e | grep $PID` where $PID is the id from step1. It corresponded to `nm-applet`
3. Run `killall nm-applet`. Wait for some time until windows are closed.
4. Run `nm-applet &` to show the applet in top bar.

Comment: Another solution that does exactly what you were doing would be to use `xkill`. Just run it and click on the window, the corresponding process will be killed. However, having exactly the same effect, this would also require you to manually run nm-applet afterwards.